# How do I solve this problem android firebase build gradle error?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to make an application through Flutter and Firebase, but I keep getting this error and I can't solve it. I would appreciate your help.

Here is the error code.

`Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:

> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Here is my code in build.gradle(android)

```
`buildscript {ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'repositories {google()mavenCentral()}
```

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

```
plugins {id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false}
```